how delete helm chart from GitLab package with api call
I'm using GitLab package for the helm chart but I'm unable to delete the helm chart from GitLab package using gitlab API
Method I tried: I tried curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: TOKEN" "https://gitlab.test.in/api/v4/projects/:id/packages/helm/:stable/charts/:test-0.160.0.tgz"
Is there any way to delete helm chart from GitHub package using gitlab API ?

You want to delete a package from GitHub but you're mentioning an URL from the GitLab API. Those are two different services.
